# Xcode 4 ARC recheck error - "changes retain/release properties of pointer"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

Trying pass the recheck of ARC conversion, but I am not sure how to fix this issue.  The method and the property are at odds and I am not sure what to do here:

```
- (void)getObjects:(id *)objects andKeys:(id *)keys {
     return [self.items getObjects:objects andKeys:keys];
}

@interface SoapArray : SoapObject <NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, NSCoding, NSFastEnumeration> {
      NSMutableArray* items;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* items;
```

ERRORS WITH:

**Sending '__autoreleasing id *' to parameter of type '__unsafe_unretained id *' changes retain/release properties of pointer**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update your signature to match the new ARC-compatible `getObjects:andKeys:`

```
- (void)getObjects:(id __unsafe_unretained [])objects andKeys:(id __unsafe_unretained [])keys;
```

The default memory semantic here would be `__autoreleasing`, but this method returns `__unsafe_unretained` objects, so you need to as well.

Keep in mind that these are `__unsafe_unretained`. When you get back your array of `id`, they have no memory management applied to them. So if `self` goes away, these objects probably will, too (and they won't zero the pointers like a `weak` property). That's usually ok and what you want, but keep it in mind.